# I am receiving the error for selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is what I have coded:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver=webdriver.chrome(r"C:\Users\aq\Desktop\Selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

driver .get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/")

print(driver.title)

driver.close
```

This is the error:

```
C:\Users\aq\PycharmProjects\Selenium_Project\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/aq/PycharmProjects/Selenium_Project/Multibrowser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aq/PycharmProjects/Selenium_Project/Multibrowser", line 4, in <module>
    driver=webdriver.chrome(r"C:\Users\aq\Desktop\Selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try to download new CHROME DRIVER according to installed chrome version**

**[from here!](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)**

---

**And place it with your main.py i.e. main operating file**

means in same folder

**update the chrome driver location in code**

```
web_driver = webdriver.Chrome("location/location/chromedriver.exe")
```

or

**simply use just like in code given below**

note- if main.py and chromedriver.exe is in same folder, no need to write full path, just type chromedriver.exe only........

```
from selenium import webdriver

web_driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://www.google.co.in/"

while True:
  web_driver.get(url)
  break
```

---

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `webdriver.Chrome` function takes a capital C. Please try to replace :

```
driver=webdriver.chrome(r"C:\Users\aq\Desktop\Selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
```

With :

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\aq\Desktop\Selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update function to `Chrome` with capital 'C' and remove the additional space in the line `driver.get`
Your code should look like this:

```
driver=webdriver.Crome(r"C:\Users\aq\Desktop\Selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/")
print(driver.title)
```